# KineticJS android stage size

Tags: javascript, android, height, width, kineticjs

Definining KineticJS Stage I go like this:

```
  var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 320,
    height: 480
  });
```

So width and height of stage are fixed size. 
How to stretch it to fit on phone screen if resolution is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is really a javascript question. You want to make the size of the stage same as the window size. This worked for me on my android project:

```
 var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: window.innerWidth,
      height: window.innerHeight
 });
```

**Edit:**
Additionally, I recommend you add jQuery as well so you can check for orientation changes, then you can do something like:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {  //this function will resize your stage to the size of your window
    stage.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
    stage.setHeight(window.innerHeight);
    stage.draw(); //redraw the stage, not sure if really needed, but good to have.
}
```

or you could do:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    stage.setScale(x,y); //set x, y scale values when the orientation changes
    stage.draw(); //redraw the stage, not sure if really needed, but good to have.
}
```

Comment: Does KineticJS takes care about scaling touch events ?

Comment: Scales alright for me. Here, take a look at this example, you'll see you can still drag correctly, no matter what the scale. http://cs.neiu.edu/~tsam/planets/index.phtml  works for both touch and desktop

Comment: Thanks this helped me very much!
But I have another problem :
It scales perfect now but when I touch screen it blinks transparent blue color all over div tag.
I am usint [this](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-desktop-and-mobile-support/) example.

Comment: thats a browser topic, rather than kineticJS, so I'll refer you to these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224433/how-can-i-disable-highlighting-in-html-or-js  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3463527/when-you-touch-an-html-element-in-safari-on-the-ipad-it-turns-gray-what-is-the  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9254252/how-to-disable-highlighting-of-a-canvas-on-tap-for-nexus-galaxy

Comment: One of those three should help you out.