# How to make stage compatible with multiple screen sizes Kineticjs

Tags: android, webkit, kineticjs

In java I would have set screen size to lets say 320x480, do all I have to do with static pixel size and than if needed stretch it to fit screen. That made my work a peace of cake. But with Kineticjs I have issues with screen size. If I do it like this

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
container: 'container',
width: window.innerWidth,
height: window.innerHeight
});
```

than I can't use static pixels for drawing. 
Also tried to set static stage size:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
container: 'container',
width: 480,
height: 320
});
```

and then stretch it :

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){
stage.setHeight( window.innerHeight);
stage.setWidth(window.innerWidth);
}, false);
```

didn't work.

What is the way to support multiple screen sizes on android phones with KineticJS?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "can't use static pixels for drawing"? You're not really doing anything wrong, but something else you could try is scaling the stage.

Comment: stage.setScale(x,y); where x and y are percentages, so the default scale for each is x=1, y=1. You can stretch the stage by some the scale: stage.setScale(0.5,2.0); //compress x by a half, double y

Comment: Also, don't forget to do stage.draw() after modifying your stage.

Comment: I want to be able to use static pixels. Lets say 320x480. And when drawing 3 rectangles one after another (in same line) 
|------||------||------| width 100px each I want them to fit screen if screen width is lets say 500px rather then use just 300px from 500px screen.

Comment: then scaling is the way to do it, you can scale anything, from shapes, to layers, to the entire stage

Comment: but what you really want to do is calculate the size of the rectangle  as a portion of the screen rather than use the 'static pixels' method. say your screen is 500 across, and you want 3 rectangles, then you can just do var rectLength = stage.getWidth()/3;

Comment: if you want some more help, put together a jsfiddle with what you tried so far and where you're stuck.

Comment: You can refer the following question and reply
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14989824/kineticjs-android-stage-size#_=_